# Macro to Copy/Paste Data

Tags: vba

Here is the code I have. I am trying to find the last populated row in a range. Then copy that data as formulas to the next blank row in the range. Finally copy the last populated row again and paste it to the second to last populated row as values. In a nutshell, move the formulas in the last row/cells down one row and retain that data where it was copied as numbers. So when new data is brought into the file, the formulas recalculate and I do not lose the previous calculated data. Hopefully that makes sense. The below code runs but does not appear to do anything other than to paste the data as values in the existing rows. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Data Copy()

Dim myLastCell As Range
Set myLastCell = LastCell(Worksheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E7:J76"))

Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E7:J" & myLastCell.Row).Copy
Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E7:J" & myLastCell.Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E7:J" & myLastCell.Row).Copy
Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E7:J" & myLastCell.Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'Retain Yesterday's YTD Metric Data

Function LastCell(r As Range) As Range

Dim LastRow&, lastCol%

On Error Resume Next

With r

LastRow& = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

lastCol% = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column

End With

Set LastCell = r.Cells(LastRow&, lastCol%)

End Function
```

[VBA Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LHZx.png)

Comment: Why you are using special characters in variable names? :)

Comment: @DavidG. If you are referring to the `&` and `%`, they are type identifiers - `&` is `Long`, `%` is `Integer`.  Hangover from the really, really, old days when `As Integer` etc didn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LastCell` function isn't doing what you think it is doing, because it is determining the row and column within **the worksheet** of the last used cell in the range, and then using that as an offset from the start of **the range**.

So if the last used row in `E7:J76` was row 10, and the last used column was column I, the cell being returned from your function is cell `M16` (i.e. 9 rows below `E7`, and 8 columns to the right).

Change

```
Set LastCell = r.Cells(LastRow&, lastCol%)
```

to be

```
Set LastCell = r.Cells(LastRow& - r.Row + 1, lastCol% - r.Column + 1)
```

or to

```
Set LastCell = r.Worksheet.Cells(LastRow&, lastCol%)
```

---

The parts where you are copying the formulas, and then replacing with values, should be something like:

```
Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E" & myLastCell.Row).Resize(1, 6).Copy
Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E" & myLastCell.Row + 1).Resize(1, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E" & myLastCell.Row).Resize(1, 6).Value = _
          Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E" & myLastCell.Row).Resize(1, 6).Value
```

That can be rewritten using a `With` block to save a few keystrokes:

```
With Sheets("YTD Metric Calculator").Range("E" & myLastCell.Row).Resize(1, 6)
    .Copy
    .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: I have added a picture to the original question of what I am trying to do. Attempting to copy a single row, which is the last populated row, down one to the next blank row, as formulas (each cell has a formula to pull in the data you see). Then take that single row you just copied and paste it back as values, to retain the data.

Comment: @Kittrell I had overlooked that you were copying from row 7 to the last row, rather than just the last row itself.  I have updated the answer to just work on the last row.

Comment: Perfect, this ended up being exactly what I needed. I very much appreciate the help. I have now fully automated my file.